Release file issue of my repository
Getting this error on latest Ubuntu (24-04).
The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gamabhana-team/gamabhana/ubuntu noble Release' does not have a Release file.

This command used to work on earlier versions of Ubuntu.
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gamabhana-team/gamabhana

Does it mean I can not install the package?

You can view https://launchpad.net/~gamabhana-team/+archive/ubuntu/gamabhana  (taken from your provided details) to view what releases that PPA or Personal Package Archive provides support for., ie. releases up to 23.04 only.

FYI:   A user on this site (https://askubuntu.com/users/124466/archisman-panigrahi) maybe able to provide more details useful in a solution; sorry I've just responded to details provided in your question
